# Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved (Wrong wsdl url)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl, service-reference

When adding a web reference or a service reference, visual studio 2010 shows the following error message. Actual wsdl url is `http://x.x.x.x:9999/PersonCRUD.asmx?wsdl`. I don't know why visual studio tries to download from `http://x.x.x.x/PersonCRUD.asmx?wsdl`

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://x.x.x.x/PersonCRUD.asmx?wsdl'.
There was an error downloading 'http://x.x.x.x/PersonCRUD.asmx?wsdl'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://x.x.x.x:9999/PersonCRUD.asmx'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://x.x.x.x:9999/PersonCRUD.asmx'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

At the end of the wsdl there is the part that contains the wrong urls. I guess it's the source of the problem. (port :9999 is missing)

```
<wsdl:port name="PersonCRUDSoap" binding="tns:PersonCRUDSoap">
    <soap:address location="http://78.186.32.181/PersonCRUD.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="PersonCRUDSoap12" binding="tns:PersonCRUDSoap12">
    <soap12:address location="http://78.186.32.181/PersonCRUD.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
```

BTW I tried this in a fresh new web site project.

Is there anyone who have a clue why this error occurs?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the internal urls in the wsdl correct? Can you provide a link/sample? It's possible that if you're exposing the wsdl yourself through WCF, you're binding to multiple endpoints and the wsdl is endpoint-specific

Comment: No all the urls are external in wsdl. i guess i can share the wsdl url `http://78.186.32.181:9999/PersonCRUD.asmx?wsdl`. I just edited the question and specified the wrong urls in the wsdl.

Comment: The WCF Test client (run `wcftestclient` from the VS2010 command prompt) can see the service and allows me to execute calls but also points at the default port not 9999. Can you please post your service's (web/app).config service section (or the place you define it in code) so we can see how it's configured? obviously obfuscate anything you consider sensitive. It certainly seems to be a service issue not a VS issue as I'm seeing the same problem. Are you attempting to proxy the connection?